# c# Print text vertically but characters remain horizontal

Tags: c#, printing

Is it possible to print using printdocument a string like in the image below. That is to print vertically while the text remains horizontal. All my searches which print vertically involve rotating the string which rotates the characters.

My code for this is wildly inefficient and static in that it only takes into account the word PRODUCT. In fact I'm embarrassed to even post it here, but you can see it below. I fix the position of each character. The problem here is that the word PRODUCT can change dynamically, so the code below will not work.

Are there any built in functions that perform this for strings much like e.Graphics.RotateTransform?

```
e.Graphics.DrawString("P", probsoltext, Brushes.Black, new PointF(28, 406));
e.Graphics.DrawString("R", probsoltext, Brushes.Black, new PointF(28, 423));
e.Graphics.DrawString("O", probsoltext, Brushes.Black, new PointF(28, 441));
e.Graphics.DrawString("D", probsoltext, Brushes.Black, new PointF(28, 459));
e.Graphics.DrawString("U", probsoltext, Brushes.Black, new PointF(28, 476));
e.Graphics.DrawString("C", probsoltext, Brushes.Black, new PointF(28, 495));
e.Graphics.DrawString("T", probsoltext, Brushes.Black, new PointF(28, 513));
```

[image]

Comment: Any code created for this problem?

Comment: Probably there is no such methods, your manual work seems to be good solution, but you always have to calculate if it fit the page ..

Comment: @P.K. How about using StringFormat?

Comment: With StringFormat you can rotate the whole text,so letters are also rotated

Comment: `StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical` works as expected only for CJK characters. (The characters are not rotated.) Since standard (Latin alphabet) characters are mostly proportional, it is not possible to simply rotate the characters. Unfortunately it do not work even with fixed width characters. There are only two options: 1. Add enter after each character. 2. Make universal code (cycle) that prints each time a single character on a new position.

Answer (score 0):

Hope following code helps.

```
System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        string drawString = "Product";
        System.Drawing.Font drawFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16);
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush drawBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
        float x = 100.0f;
        float y = 15.0f;
        System.Drawing.StringFormat drawFormat = new System.Drawing.StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical);
        formGraphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, x, y, drawFormat);
        drawFont.Dispose();
        drawBrush.Dispose();
        formGraphics.Dispose();
```

Following line will do the trick

```
System.Drawing.StringFormat drawFormat = new System.Drawing.StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical);
```

Comment: I tried your code. The characters are sideways and not like in the picture I posted above.

Comment: What is the end goal? You want to display something like a table where 1st column will have a common value for few rows; which will be vertically aligned?

Comment: I want it to look like the image in my OP. It is basically a table with the first column being the title.The user will be able to change the language of the title, which will change the characters. That's why my manual solution is useless here. But it's important that the characters are readable and not rotated.

Comment: Ok. But I don't think you will get anything readymade. The workaround may be to use a "TableLayoutPanel"? Just a thought. Because you can have a control in any of the cells and apply rowspan to merge no of columns as per your need. Just like creating a table in HTML.